# How to say "That looks delicious"

Tags: phrase, equivalent-phrase

In company, or at someone's house, how might I say "That dish looks delicious?" or "That looks good"?

My inclination is to say 那看起来好吃, or maybe 那看地好吃, but both seem like too much of a direct translation. How might a Chinese person express that thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

这桌菜看样子很好吃。The food served ("tableful of food") looks delicious.

食物看起来很不错。The food looks great.

Actually there is nothing wrong with 看起来 and 好吃. 
If you would like to show off your skills, use a chengyu, [here's a list](http://wenda.tianya.cn/question/05b80a66f56dff43).

Comment: I think people may fall off their chairs if I pull out chengyu :) 看样子很好吃 sounds good, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That dish looks delicious. 那个菜看起来很好吃。

That looks good.  那个看起来不错。